# how can we use cancan gem without being log-in?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, cancan

I am trying to make a cancan permissions for visitor who doesn't have to login to get some services. To clarify this for example:-

I've a search controller which has new and search actions . In the related new viewer there's some links, some of them I don't want to be seen for non-login users and others must be seen for them!..

I've tried to write these lines in the controller search :-

```
before_filter :authenticate_user! # this forces the user to log-in ( I don't want this )
load_and_authorize_resource # this doesn't work without authenticate_user
before_filter :load_permissions
```

in the new view I wrote this

```
<%= link_to "Listing Managment", extras_path if can? :index, Role %>
```

but it raises an error for me because of ( can? )

> hint: the error arises when I remove the controller's 3 before filter
>   above. But still not convenient when I put them.

Comment: `load_and_authorize_resource` will work fine without authenticating a user. It depends on how you've written your abilities. If you add those to the question, or the error you're getting, we may be able to help you.

Comment: Thanks for replies, but actually I have found a very simple solution .

by making if user_signed_in? condition for the link_to that I want to be displayed only for log-in users. just like this :-

    <% if user_signed_in? %>
   <%= link_to "Listing Managment", extras_path if can? :index, Role %>
 <% end %>

by this condition the error of ( undefined method `role' for nil:NilClass ) wont appear, as the non-login user wont see this link at all ( and that what I wanted ).

Comment: I think you're going about things the wrong way, and you need to read the cancan documentation.

Comment: I have configured dynamic cancan for my project, so may be I've some differences from the normal one. from this tutorial  http://blog.joshsoftware.com/2012/10/23/dynamic-roles-and-permissions-using-cancan/
cancan doc. doesn't include a high details for configuring abilities  dynamically .

Comment: in a single word - yuck.

Comment: Thanks for your attempt to help me.

Answer (score 2):

In your cancan initializer you can use something like

user = current_user || User.new

That way cancan will pick up the current user (who may have roles) and if there is no current_user (you are not logged in) will return a dummy user record (anonymous user) with no active roles.

Comment: This line of code is introduced by cancan ability.rb as a default. but I don't know how to configure it if I'm using the dynamic cancan . I've tried to put this line in the ability.rb but It doesn't work fine with me! . this's the dynamic cancan ability.rb file https://github.com/prasadsurase/dynacan/blob/master/app/models/ability.rb